# Error deploying endpoint containing parameter of type "file"

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm trying to deploy a simple endpoint which contains a [parameter of type `file`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types) .

I'm using the `gcloud service-management deploy` command with the following openapi compliant yaml:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  description: "Image API"
  title: "Image API"
  version: "v1"

host: "image-api.endpoints.myproject.cloud.goog"
basePath: "/v1"

schemes:
- "https"

paths:
  "/images":
    post:
      description: "Adds an image"
      operationId: "add"
      consumes:
      - "multipart/form-data"      
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        201:
          description: "An image create response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ImageResponse"
      parameters:
      - name: filepath
        in: formData
        required: true
        type: string
      - name: image
        in: formData
        required: false
        type: file

definitions:
  ImageResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
      thumbnail_url:
        type: string
```

But getting the following error:

```
 ERROR: unknown location: http: repeated message field 'google.protobuf.Struct.fields' referred to by message 'AddRequest' cann
ot be mapped as an HTTP parameter.
 ERROR: unknown location: http: cyclic message field 'google.protobuf.Struct.FieldsEntry.value' referred to by message 'AddRequ
est' cannot be mapped as an HTTP parameter.
 ERROR: unknown location: http: cyclic message field 'google.protobuf.ListValue.values' referred to by message 'AddRequest' can
not be mapped as an HTTP parameter.'
```

If I take the `file` parameter out the endpoint is successfully deployed.
Is that a Google Cloud Endpoint limitation or is there another way to define it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints does not currently support uploading of images.

You could upload to Google Cloud Storage first:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics

And then pass the URL to your Google Cloud Endpoints, which could then retrieve the image from Google Cloud Storage and perform processing.

Comment: My backend can accept a file on an endpoint, but there's no file parameter on the openapi.yaml. So you won't get Cloud Endpoints feature semantics on the file parameters, but the request/response itself works. That seems a lot easier than having to upload to cloud storage and then call the endpoint with the blob id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload file instead of type file use it like below

```html
- in: formData
  name: file
  description: Upload file
  type: string
  format: binary
```