# Cloud Endpoint - Not accepting Multipart file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-2.0

I have more than 30 methods exposed using Cloud Endpoints. All works perfectly except 2 methods where I have following specification, in short

From yaml I have marked in bold the particular part where issue occurs. If I remove, file is properly parsed and deployed.

Please refer the last 4 lines starting from --> in: "formData"

```
    post:
      tags:
      - "Companies"
      description: "Add a new company"
      operationId: "addCompany"
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
      - in: "formData"
        name: "name"
        description: "name of the company"
        type: "string"
      - in: "formData"
        name: "map"
        description: "map of the company (JSON)"
        type: "string"
        required: true
      - in: "formData"
        name: "hardnesses"
        description: "list of hardnesses seperate by semicolon ;"
        type: "string"
      - in: "formData"
        name: "file"
        description: "Company logo"
        type: "file"
```

So it means will I not be able to upload a file?

Thanks for your valuable inputs.

(Issue is in Github: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1392 )

Comment: Are you getting an error when you deploy? If so, could you please update the question to include it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error deploying endpoint containing parameter of type "file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059304/error-deploying-endpoint-containing-parameter-of-type-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints does not currently support parameter of type "file".

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082563)

Comment: FYI, once you earn 15 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to flag questions as duplicates of other questions, as seems to be the case here.

Comment: My backend can accept a file on an endpoint, but there's no file parameter on the openapi.yaml. So you won't get Cloud Endpoints feature semantics on the file parameters, but the request/response itself works.